# wso2 esb error Cannot get all services. Backend service may be unavailable

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, wso2-esb

Hi am working with WSO2 ESB 4.7.0

I am facing an error while accessing the wso2 esb management console as shown below.

Error says that one of my service is unable retrieve security scenario for service.

```
The following error details are available. Please refer logs for more details.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Cannot get all services. Backend service may be unavailable
at org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.ServiceAdminClient.handleException(ServiceAdminClient.java:428)
at org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.ServiceAdminClient.getAllServices(ServiceAdminClient.java:89)
at org.apache.jsp.service_002dmgt.index_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.service_002dmgt.index_jsp:167)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:177)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Cannot retrieve security scenario for service GeoLocationInsertion2.0
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:367)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:413)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:224)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
at org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.stub.ServiceAdminStub.listServices(ServiceAdminStub.java:8211)
at org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.ServiceAdminClient.getAllServices(ServiceAdminClient.java:87)
```

[image]
Any Suggestions....

Thanks...!

Comment: your main error is related with this one: Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Cannot retrieve security scenario for service GeoLocationInsertion2.0. Can you provide some information about this?

Comment: Hi Jorge Infante Osorio thanks for the reply GeoLocationInsertion2.0 service is working fine am facing this error in management console i have added a image for more information.

Comment: Stop the server. Try to remove the folder content in [WSO2_HOME]\repository\deployment\server\servicemetafiles\ and start the server. Make a copy of this file in another location before that

Comment: hii Jorge yesterday i have just removed the meta file of the particular service which is causing this problem and restarted the server and it worked,Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great news, please mark my response as the right answer :-D

Comment: Hi Jorge Plz post ur comment in the answer filed so that i can mark it as right.

Comment: Hi plz look in to the below link and help me if u have any solution 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478909/wso2esb-authentication-service-exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop the server. Try to remove the folder content in [WSO2_HOME]\repository\deployment\server\servicemetafiles\ and start the server. Make a copy of this file in another location before that